# Show that $X_i$ is a subspace of $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$.

Tags: general-topology

Show that $X_i$ is a subspace of $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ (All $X_i$ non-empty). Ok, I have to find an embedding, but which function to choose?

I am familiar with a theorem that states when a any topological space $Y$ is subspace of a product space. (It states necessary and sufficient conditions, requests, and among other things, that $Y$ has the weak topology generated by a family of functions $\{f_i : f_i: Y \to X_i\}.$ But, I really don't know how to proceed. It seems to be something obvious...

Comment: This requires that all the $X_j$ be nonempty. Yes, it's very obvious. Draw a picture of $A\times B$. See if you can find something that looks like $A$ in that picture...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich you mean seriously that it helps?

Comment: @Leonardo: Yes, it can. To relate it to my answer, note that for each $b\in B$ the set $A\times\{b\}$ does for $A$ what my set does for $X_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For each $j\in I\setminus\{i\}$ pick a point $p_j\in X_j$, and consider the subset

$$\left\{x\in\prod_{j\in I}X_j:x_j=p_j\text{ for all }j\in I\setminus\{i\}\right\}$$

of the product. Two points in this set differ *only* in the $i$-th coordinate.

Comment: ok! so, what do you mean? I undestand the set, but, what are it saying?

Comment: @Leonardo: There’s a very natural homeomorphism between that set and $X_i$. Once you figure out what that homeomorphism (or its inverse) is, proving that it *is* a homeomorphism is pretty straightforward.

Comment: thank you, I am not seeing yet, I will think more.

Comment: @Leonardo: Here’s a small further hint. The projection map from the product to the space $X_i$ takes a point $x=\langle x_j:j\in I\rangle$ to the coordinate point $x_i$. Now look at the restriction of that map to the set in my answer.

Comment: it has to be an injective map? @Brian

Comment: @Leonardo: The restriction that I described *is* injective.

Comment: but it is also surjective!

Comment: @Leonardo: Which is a very good thing, since a homeomorphism between two spaces has to be a bijection!

Comment: Now I have to show that it is an open map, since it is already continuous! But it is open, once the projection map is open...

Comment: @Leonardo: Right: the projection map is open, so you need only check that its restriction to the subspace is still open. There’s a little work to be done there, but it’s not too hard.

Comment: It is easy since it is a bijection.... it follows directly.

Comment: I am sorry that this page has not a directly comunication, as a personal chat... Do you mind if I ask to you some advices in how to think about general topology, it is my worst hability, and I would appreciate some experience, in how to think on problems, definitions, etc... do you suggest any channel? email, etc? (I mean, if you wish and don't mind I will appreciate)

Comment: @Leonardo: It’s not enough that it’s a bijection. Here’s an example. Let $X$ be the reals with the usual topology, and let $Y$ be the reals with the discrete topology. Let $D=\{\langle x,x\rangle:x\in\Bbb R\}$, and let $\pi:X\times Y\to X$ be the projection. Then $D$ is a closed subset of $X\times Y$, $\pi$ is an open map, and the restriction of $\pi$ to $D$ is a bijection, but $the restriction of $\pi$ to $D$ is *not* an open map. Thus, the fact that in our problem the restriction *is* open depends on the nature of the set that I defined in my answer.

Comment: you are right! I got it!

Comment: @Leonardo: You can reach me at `b.scott@csuohio.edu`, but anything sent to that address goes through two spam filters that aren’t under my control, so be sure to put `[MSE]` in the subject line.

Comment: @Leonardo: And it arrived. I have a dinner guest tonight and probably won’t be able to answer until tomorrow, but I will get to it.

Comment: I am really thankful to you!  Sincerely